# Eclipse Changes Directions?

Tags: lunar-eclipse

How could the lunar eclipse of January 20, 2019 begin from bottom to top and then finish from left to right?  Here's the video of it's progression's directions.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A2sTkuZht4s

Answer (score 3):

Because we are standing on a rotating globe.  We are changing direction as the Earth spins. This appears exaggerated in the video as the horizon is not visible, so there is no way of seeing how the camera was rotated to view the moon as the eclipse progressed.

Relative to the stars, the moon appears to enter the Earth's shadow from one side and leave it from the other,